# Python 3.6 - heroku local command cannot find Procfile - Help troubleshooting error message

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, null, local

I am trying to get a working example of my Django app before deployment to Heroku server. If I run `python manage.py` or `heroku open` the website runs with no problems. When I attempt to run `heroku local web` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Jup\Drop>heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[WARN] Cannot read property '1' of null
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run_foreman.js --help
```

My Procfile is definitely there, in my root directory where my .env file and my `manage.py` files are located. I then try `heroku local -f Profile` which force searches for the Procfile in a location (which defaults to current folder) and I get a similar error:

```
C:\Users\Jup\Drop>heroku local -f Procfile
[WARN] Cannot read property '1' of null
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See heroku.js --help
 !    Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

It still can't find the file, and I have no idea what `.json` file it's looking for. I search my directory for "null" and there are a bunch of files in my bootstrap that has that name, but it's just a warning and I'm not sure if matters. If you could help me troubleshoot, or point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. My project directory looks like:

> Project Directory

```
Root Directory(Drop)/
  -Buylist/
      --apps
      --templates
  -project/
      --settins
      --views etc.
  -.env
  -manage.py
  -Pipfile
  -Pipfile.lock
  -Procfile
```

> Procfile

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi
worker: celery worker -E --app=project.celery.app
```

I'm not sure what other info you may need, but I can provide it. Just let me know!

Comment: Please show your directory structure. And do you have a requirements.txt?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added my structure. `Pipfile.lock` and `pipfile` takes the place of requirements.txt.

Comment: For some reason your app isn't being recognised as a Python project. I'm not sure when support for Pipfile was added but it was relatively recently - perhaps your local version of the Heroku runtime is out of date?

Comment: I also had the same error before I switched to Piplock. I thought it may have been due to the Git folder being in a different working directory, so I copied the files where my other .py projects are located but I got the same error

Comment: @juju did you managed to solve this issue?